# calling django translation values using include tag not displayed

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation

I am using django 1.7.2 and python 2.7.

I have a number of templates that use a number of translated variables.

I thought that it reasonable to place the translated variables in its own page and then use an include tag to place the translated value on the required template pages. But this approach does not work!

Does anyone know why this does not work or a workaround?

Here is what I currently have:

I have added the following include tag on my template pages:

```
{% include "my_details/summary_details_translations.html" %}
```

This is the contents of the `summary_details_translations.html` page:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% trans "Summary Details" as resume_detail_temp_value %}
```

The `{{ resume_detail_temp_value }}` in my template pages do not display a value.

I have tested that the address of the include is correct by adding simple text data to the `summary_details_translations.html` page, which does display on the template pages.

Comment: The variable `resume_detail_temp_value` is local to the `summary_details_translations.html`.

Comment: thanks - that makes sense.